# How can I see thumbnails of images in nautilus in a browser's file selection dialog?

Tags: gnome, nautilus

In Gnome 42, Nautilus does not show me image thumbnails in the file dialog. In Ubuntu 18.04, when selecting an image for upload, the file-selection dialog displays a thumbnail of the image on the right side when it is selected. Now, this does not happen and I cannot find the option to enable it.

I would like to know if it is because this is not yet available in this version of Nautilus, or maybe it will not be available again or if there is any way to make this possible.

Comment: Revise the body of your question. It is very unclear, and you did not do any attempt to improve readability by splitting in sections and using appropriate punctuation.

Comment: sorry, I'll try another way,when I try to upload an image from the browser a file manager tab will open from which I choose which files I want to upload, in the previous version of the gnome file manager I could see a thumbnail on the right side and I could see what image I am uploading, in ubuntu 22.04 this does not happen,I can only see the name and a very small and a small thumbnail next to it, I wanted to know if there is any way to to be able to activate again the option to see a preview with the information and the thumbnail of the image that I try to upload with a "readable" size

Comment: Question itself is now more clear indeed. Add any relevant information directly to your question (use "edit"): not everybody will read the comments and these may disappear.

Comment: yes, that answered my question, thank you very much for your time and for the information